# Perl save file from website to desktop

Tags: perl

I have this script below, where I want to download a pdf from a URL

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $save = "C:\\Users\\rahard\\Desktop\\";  
my $file = get 'http://locationoffile';
```

How can I save the pdf to the Desktop? (if I click the URL, it will pront me to save a random name file)

Thank you

/edit some syntax error in $save and edit $file location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to open a file handle and print to it. Also note that each backslash in `$save` must be escaped.

```
my $save = "C:\\Users\\rahard\\Desktop\\";  
my $file = get 'http://file.pdf';

open( FILE, '>', $save . 'filename.pdf' ) or die $!;
binmode FILE;
print FILE $file;
close( FILE );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But again, I need to open the url, and get the file (because mainly the file from the URL has a random name everytime downloaded). So I can"t specify open( FILE, '>', $save . 'filename.pdf' ) because filename.pdf will be random..

Comment: and also, if I specify the filename.pdf manually, the file is not properlly downloaded (so when I download the pdf, it says the file is not encoded properly)

Comment: @rahardi: Make sure that the file is saved binary. I updated by response and added a line. [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) is necessary on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the url is not the origin location of the pdf and you get redirected to them?
If the response of `get` is not a valid pdf, it could be the html-content of the redirecting page.

I would test this first.

Therefor I would use `WWW::Mechanize` or a similar library.